# How does desktop software spoof GPS location on iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

There are a few desktop softwares(like [itools](https://www.thinkskysoft.com/virtual-location-2/)) out there that can be used to virtually set the location of the phone anywhere in the world.

I'm very confused on how is this possible? How can your cheat the GPS into making it thinks it's somewhere else?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: I was wondering the same and found an open-source solution that internally, probably, does the same: [LocationSimulator](https://github.com/Schlaubischlump/LocationSimulator). Specifically [this code snippet](https://github.com/Schlaubischlump/LocationSimulator/blob/27a5f648c2c07901973769472503a77d23021274/LocationSimulator/MobileDevice/devicelocation/devicelocation.c#L76) is responsible for spoofing the location

Answer (score 0):

With a [`gpx file`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/gpx), you can simulate your location anywhere you like (for testing purposes). You can do this with Xcode when your phone is connected. But there is a bug and it's keep you in that fake location if you pull off the cable without selecting `Don't Simulate Location` before.

Comment: What a trick. I don't know how much this **BUG** will consist.

Comment: Last version I checked is Xcode 10.2.1 and it still works.